# Converting a year and day (e.g. 2013216 = the 216th day of 2013) into a full date in Java

Tags: java, database, date, datetime, calendar

Context: I have two tables in a Database, onee which stores a date as a day of the year appended to the year itself, and one which stores a date as a full  date. I need to compare the two so I only select rows from table B where the full date is the same day as the day date in table A.

I have a date as a year and a day (such as 2014234 which is the 234th day of this year) and I need to convert it into a full date format like: 11-OCT-13 15.30.54.000000000 +02:00 so I can compare the two for the purpose of selecting fields from a table the rows where the day the full date(e.g. 11-OCT) is the same as the day of day date (e.g. 2014235).

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for your help everyone! I've managed to get the date converted, I've now got two dates in the same format, and I need to only select the rows where a column has the same DAY as the date in the other table, how can I do this? Using = checks that the two dates are equal to the millisecond, I only want to check that they are the same to the day. Do you know how I would go about this in an SQL query? Or will '11-OCT-13 = 11-OCT-13 15.30.54.000000000 +02:00' return true, for example?

Comment: When you have another question, search Stackoverflow.com first. If not found, post another question rather than append to this question. But you *will* find hundreds of questions already answered on the topic of SQL and Java date-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) that:

```
DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDD");
Date dt = dt.parse(theString, 0);
```

`y` is the "year" field, `D` is the "day in year" field.

If you need to then convert it back to a string in another format, you can use another instance with the relevant format and its [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.text.FieldPosition-) method.

Comment: @R.T. `yyyyDD` also works if the actual day number is 3 digits.

Comment: Will this convert for example 2014001 (1st of January) into a Date format like 11-OCT-13 15.30.54.000000000 +02:00?

Comment: @user2534905: See the final paragraph. The code sample converts to a `Date`. You'd use a second instance with a different format and its `format` method to convert the `Date` into a string in a different format.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've managed to get the date converted, I've now got two dates in the same format, and I need to only select the rows where a column has the same DAY as the date in the other table, how can I do this? Using = checks that the two dates are equal to the millisecond, I only want to check that they are the same to the day. Do you know how I would go about this in an SQL query? Or will '11-OCT-13 = 11-OCT-13 15.30.54.000000000 +02:00' return true, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDD").parse(String.valueOf(234));
```

Comment: Hi thanks, will this convert a variable with the value 2014001 for example, into a date with a format like 11-OCT-13 15.30.54.000000000 +02:00?

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601 – Ordinal Date

Your String format is called an [ordinal date](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_8601) format. The standard define an expanded version with a hyphen between the year and the day-of-year as well as the basic format you have in hand where the hyphen is omitted.

I suggest using the hyphen as it is more recognizable and readable for humans.

## Avoid j.u.Date and .Calendar

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package bundled with Java 8.

Both Joda-Time and java.time offer a LocalDate class to represent a date-only without any time-of-day or time zone.

## Joda-Time

Joda-Time has great support for ISO 8601 formats.

Here is some example code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4.

```
String input = "2013216";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormatter.basicOrdinalDate();
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( input" );
```